# Read un named string array from Mongo using Pig

Tags: mongodb, load, apache-pig

I have a records which look  as below in mongo.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "gender":"male", "age" : 19, "cars" : ["a", "b", "c"], "first" : "Daniel", "last" : "Alabi" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "gender":"male", "age" : 21, "cars" : ["d", "e"], "first" : "Tolu", "last" : "Alabi" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "gender":"female", "age" : 50, "cars" : [], "first" : "Tinuke", "last" : "Dada" }
```

I would like to have the schema as 
'f:chararray, l:chararray, g:chararray, age:int, cars:{t:(car:chararray)}'
after loading data in pig.

I tried using

```
TEMP = LOAD 'mongodb://localhost:27017/local.temp' USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoLoader('first:chararray, last:chararray, age:int, gender:chararray, cars:{(chararray)}');

DESCRIBE TEMP;
```

I am getting output as

```
(Daniel,Alabi,19,male,)

(Tolu,Alabi,21,male,)

(Tinuke,Dada,50,female,{})

TEMP: {first: chararray,last: chararray,age: int,gender: chararray,cars: {(val_0: chararray)}}
```

Can someone please help in writing load statement?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/pig/README.md#datatype-mapping):

Mongo array is transformed into Pig Tuple.

Comment: "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes."

Comment: I looked at this page. It starts with reading data from a file. So we can add field names easily. But I am not sure if the same can be used for reading data from MongoDb.